# Algorithm: Buying a collection of goods with vouchers

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-science, complexity-theory, network-flow

I'm struggling to come up with a solution for this problem for an algorithms course:

You go to a store and want to buy *n = {n<sub>1</sub>, n<sub>2</sub>, ..., n<sub>n</sub>}* goods, where the items can be different or not.

The store has the following promotion: "If a customer buys two articles whose prices add up to a value which ends with 11, 33 or 55 cents, he will receive a voucher, worth the corresponding cent value."

The problem is to come up with an algorithm which computes an optimal strategy for buying a given collection of goods, where a minimization of the total cost is wanted.

For example:
If you need to buy 3 products (n<sub>1</sub>, n<sub>2</sub>, n<sub>3</sub>) with prices (1.01$, 2.10$ and 3$), you should buy n<sub>1</sub> and n<sub>2</sub> together and buy n<sub>3</sub> separately, yielding a total cost of:
(1.01 + 2.10) + 3 - (0.11) = 6$.

No hint is given, but I think I can use some approach of flow-networks.

Comment: So does this course give a hint about the complexity of the problem (P vs. NP-hard)?

Comment: Nope, nothing more than what was stated. :/

Answer (score 0):

Sort items you want to buy by cent prices... i.e. (25.01$, 1.02$, ..., 0.99$).

And then check... whether any of the cents sums up to 0.99$...
This can be solved easily by two sum problem... You take .01$ and look for its compliment 0.98$ using binary search... Delete this pair and repeat until you find no pair of products with cents that sum up to 0.99$.

If this is done, delete found pairs of products... calculate your gain and check whether any of the cents sums up to 0.88$... The same way.

...

If this is done, delete found pairs of products... and check whether any of the cents sums up to 0.11$... The same way.

This is all `O(nlogn)` complexity ;)

Comment: Your solution doesn't take into account multiple combinations. If you have prices like 1.05, 2.06, 0.05, 0.01, both 1.05+2.06 and 0.05+2.06 are acceptable but the second one is cheaper. So if you need to buy three items you can spend 0.05+2.06+0.01 instead of 1.05+2.06+0.01. Also, how do you make binary search work on sums? You don't know in advance which value you're looking for.

Comment: "an optimal strategy for buying a given collection of goods"... so the items are given... e.g. we want to buy 3 items that cost 1.05, 2.06, 0.05... and we save always 0.11$. It does not make difference which pair we take in that case ;)

Comment: We want to buy a given collection of goods... so, say product A, B, C. Not a given number of goods... How do I make binary search work on sums? If I am looking for two integers that add up to n... I take the first one from table... say a and look for (n-a) using binary search so that a + (n-a) = n.

Comment: Again: please read fully. If you do a binary search, you'll find the first one that matches, and there's a chance you'll miss the optimal one. If the first "middle" one in your binary search sums up to 0.11, you won't check if there's one that still sums up to 0.11 but which is cheaper, or even worse, that sums up to 0.33 or 0.55 because then you remove them from the list. E.g. 2.04 can be combined with 0.07, 0.29, 0.51, 1.07, 1.29, 1.51 and so on.

Comment: But I check for any 0.99 at first... and find them all. Only then I look for 0.88 and so on.